# Function must be defined with 1 argument

Tags: python, function, arguments

My code works as intended, but the bot code checker displays an error "The 'budget' function should be defined with 1 argument, I currently found 0 arguments in the definition."
I've tried to come up with multiple solutions, but none work.

```
invited = input("Mitu kutsutud?: ")
coming = input("Mitu tuleb?: ")

food = 10
room = 55

def budget():
    max_budget = 10 * int(kutsutud) + 55
    min_budget = 10 * int(tuleb) + 55
    print(str(max_budget) + " eurot")
    print(str(min_budget) + " eurot")
    
budget()
```

Comment: I guess the argument the function should take must be described in the problem you have. From our side, we don't know what to do.

Comment: `def budget(some_argument_name):`

Answer (score 0):

```
invited = input("Mitu kutsutud?: ")
coming = input("Mitu tuleb?: ")

food = 10
room = 55

#This function needs 2 arguments assuming you are
#trying to use kutsutud and tuleb as the int values in your function
#This also assumes that min and max budget are unchanging
#Also the data above cannot be used because the exist before the function was created

def budget(exampleA,exampleB):
    max_budget = 10 * int(kutsutud) + 55
    min_budget = 10 * int(tuleb) + 55
    print(str(max_budget) + " eurot")
    print(str(min_budget) + " eurot")
    
budget()



##################################################################################



##Make your function here.
def budget(exampleA,exampleB):
    max_budget = 10 * int(kutsutud) + 55
    min_budget = 10 * int(tuleb) + 55
    print(str(max_budget) + " eurot")
    print(str(min_budget) + " eurot")
    

# Set Vars here
invited = input("Mitu kutsutud?: ")
coming = input("Mitu tuleb?: ")

food = 10
room = 55

#Call function here
budget(invited, coming)
```

Hope this helps based on what I understood from the question.

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives me an error. Now it says i only need 1 argument not 2. This assignment is kinda messed up. No matter what i change it doesn't work.